# How to check that a string is not empty in python/only contains whitespace?

Tags: python, whitespace

I have a variable called "string" in python. How can I check that my variable does not contain only whitespace, but has an actual character in it?
If the variable contains only whitespace, I don't want to print it. If it has a character in it, then I want to print the variable.

Comment: You can do it like so: `if line.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isspace()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/isspace.html):

```
string = ' '
if not string.isspace():
  print(string)
```